# "Красные" свойства в Delphi

Tags: delphi, ide

Что обозначают свойства каких-либо компонентов, в дизайнере форм, выделенные красным цветом? К примеру, Action, ActiveControl, Menu.

Comment: Возможно, у данного компонента нет такого свойства? Когда Delphi что-то подчеркивает красным, он как бы намекает, что по его мнению на этом месте допущена ошибка.

Comment: @insolor вопрос был плохо сформулирован. ТС говорит про свойства в конструкторе форм, а не в коде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это означает привязку к чему-либо.

Например, свойство `ActiveControl` у формы означает, какой элемент управления при запуске программы будет активным (если это кнопка, то она будет выделена, а если текстовое поле (Edit, Memo), то в него можно сразу вводить текст). Свойство `Action` - привязка к действию - к процедуре (если простым языком) - событию действия `TAction OnExecute`. Если в этом свойстве выбрать какое-нибудь действие, то на обработчик `OnClick` (или `OnChange`) элемента управления оно будет выполняться так, как процедура-обработчик этих событий. Ну, а свойство `Menu` нужно форме для связи с главным меню (попробуйте поставить на форму меню (2-ой компонент закладки Standard)), и его имя отобразиться в этом свойстве.